# Virtualenv and import six module erro in django 1.4

Tags: django, virtualenv, django-modeltranslation

We install virtualenv inside every project in server:

> virtualenv env
>
> source env/bin/activate
>
> pip install -r requirements.txt

But I have stil `from django.utils.six import with_metaclass ImportError: No module named six`
error in syncdb. I have this problem with django-modeltranslation.

Why I have this error? I could import six in python.

Comment: Do you have the `six` module in your requirements.txt? by default, virtualenvs are created with --no-site-packages, so system packages are not included.

Answer (score 1):

Django 1.4 is a very old version. django-modeltranslation clearly relies on a more recent version of Django.

Comment: You are right, problem disappeared after upgrading django.